# Android camera field of view and device orientation

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I would like to fetch camera view angles in Android. There area two methods: `getVerticalViewAngle()` and `getHorizontalViewAngle()`. Do these parameters depend on device orientation or device coordinate system? Should I check display rotation and then remap vertical angle with horizontal angle?

Comment: What values do you get when you try it?

Comment: Vertical angle is 44,1 degree nad horizontal angle is 57,4 degree (Samsung Galaxy S4).